# Jquery .animate ignoring duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade in a remote image after it loads. It's working well but for some reason, the duration of the animation is getting ignored and the opacity is changing over maybe 10-15 seconds.

```
$(function(){
    var src = "myImageURL";
    var ele = $('.wrapper');
    ele.css('opacity', '0.0');
    var img = $('<img>', {
        src: src
    }).hide().appendTo(ele).on('load', function() {
        ele.css('background-image', 'url('+src+')').show();
        ele.animate({ opacity: '1.0' }, 500, 'linear', function(){
            // Other unrelated code
        };
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5gvzsgvk)

Comment: can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle or the like?

Comment: @Rooster I have created a JSFiddle. First time I've done this though and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'll update my question once I do. https://jsfiddle.net/5gvzsgvk

Comment: found the problem based on the css you put in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the css in your jsfiddle, you're setting a 15 section transition, which is overriding the javascript based animation you're adding:

These are the offending lines, remove them and it works like you described you wanted:

```
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transition: all 15s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 15s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 15s ease-in;
  transition: all 15s ease-in;
```

Comment: Just discovered this myself and came back to post the answer :) Thanks!